# Raise ulimit for ssh-agent on Sonoma

Tags: launchd

I'm running into an issue where I need more than 256 open ssh connections for a deployment pipeline. This process stalls when ssh-agent runs into the file limit. I've raised the limit via

```
launchctl limit maxfiles 4096 unlimited
```

restarted `ssh-agent` and raised the limit in the current shell however the agent appears to retain a 256 file limit. What would the appropriate way to raise the limit on a permanent basis be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly increase a \`ulimit -n\` limits?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32235/how-to-properly-increase-a-ulimit-n-limits)

Comment: That does not; besides being 12 years old, the kern.maxfiles is already larger than the values there and the commands I ran would cover the other two cases in the first answer. 

I can raise my local shell's ulimit and run ```eval `ssh-agent` ``` then things are fine. That indicates the problem is related to launchd not picking up the limits from ```launchctl limit``` when starting a process. I could just continue to do this but I'd rather not have to start a separate agent when I need the higher limit or manage which shells are using which agent.

Comment: So you created sysctl.conf and launchd.conf with the proper directives, then rebooted, and there was no change?